# MCP4151 unresponsive to commands on ESP with CircuitPython

Tags: microcontroller, spi, esp32, programming, micropython

I am trying to control an [MCP4151-103E digital potentiometer](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/22060b.pdf) from an ESP32-Devkit-v1 running CircuitPython 8.2.7.

For this task, I have the following code. This has been adapted from [this Github repository](https://github.com/HydraSpex/MCP4151/blob/main/MCP4151_lib.py) and adapted to my board.

```
import board
from micropython import const as S
## SPI pins
SPI_MOSI = S(board.D23)
SPI_MISO = S(board.D19)
SPI_CLK = S(board.D18)

## Digital pot CS pin
POT_CS = S(board.D16)

from busio import SPI as B_SPI
import digitalio

p_cs_pot = digitalio.DigitalInOut(POT_CS)
p_cs_pot.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT
p_cs_pot.value = True
print('Init: SPI')

spi = B_SPI(SPI_CLK, MOSI = SPI_MOSI, MISO = SPI_MISO)

## set pot value
async def set_pot(value = 0):
    ## value must be between 0-256
    global spi, p_cs_pot    

    print('Pot: Setting value to ' + str(value))

    while not spi.try_lock(): await asyncio.sleep(0)
    
    p_cs_pot.value = False
    
    #spi.write(bytes([0x4F, 0xFF]))
    
    msb = value >> 8
    lsb = value & 0xFF

    spi.write(bytes([msb,lsb]))

    spi.unlock()
    p_cs_pot.value = True
    
print('running loop')
while True:
    for i in range(255):
        async.run(set_pot(i))
```

The MCP4151 has wiring to the ESP32 per below:

- SDI to D23 (MOSI)
- SDI to D19 (MISO) via 10k resistor
- CLK to D18 (CLK)
- CS to D16

I have found that the MCP4151 appears to be completely unresponsive to set commands. It maintains a fixed 5k between P0W and P0A pins. P0W and P0A pins are connected only to a multimeter measuring resistance.

I have:

- Desoldered/disconnected all other devices from the SPI bus.
- Verified 3.3v supply across Vss/Vdd.
- Added delays between asserting CS (active low) and sending commands (no effect). The datasheet seems to suggest 60ns between CS and CLK, and 70ns between CS and MSB of data.
- Tried setting 0xFF at address 0x4F on the MCP4151 (TCON register).
- Verified SPI frequency is set to 10MHz.
- Added mutli-second delays between changes to CS line to verify change with multimeter.
- Tried modifying code to use the Adafruit [BusDevice](https://docs.circuitpython.org/projects/busdevice/en/latest/index.html) helpers instead.
- Tied P0W or P0A to GND or Vcc due to [this answer to another question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/395772/why-would-a-digipot-require-the-voltages-on-its-terminals-to-be-between-ground-a).

I did find [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/357655/software-spi-implementation-for-avr) with advice for the same digital pot with an AVR in C, but do not understand how to compare and apply it to my implementation as I lack familiarity with C.

[This page](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=4824) suggests that one cannot cheat with the CS line by leaving it low all the time, so it is explicitly asserted for each command.

Where do you believe the issue lies (wiring, code), and why? Note that I do not have scopes or logic analyzers available to test. Alternatively, can you provide a working example for using the MCP4151 with the ESP32 in CircuitPython?

Note that while I have added the *micropython* tag to this question, it relates to *CircuitPython*, but no *CircuitPython* tag exists and the implementations are similar.

Comment: Where in this code do you configure the spi frequency and mode? Did you try it with a much lower frequency, as in the Github repository, for a start?

Comment: I have tried this now using .configure on the SPI object with a lock immediately after declaring it. I explicitly specified the phase, polarity and baud rate. Started with 976000, also tried 100000, 256000. No luck. Thinking maybe a dud IC?